# System.MissingMemberException Was Unhandled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I don't know why this error keeps popping up, but my code never used to do this.

Here is the code:

```
Dim proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")
For i As Integer = 0 To proc.Count - 1
  proc(i).CloseMainWindow()
Next i
```

On the second line, the error occurs. Here is the error:
Public member 'Count' on type 'Process()' not found.

This code never did this until yesterday, I don't know what is causing it either. The code has no errors, so I am not sure that is causing it.

Comment: Do you have option strict enabled? You would normally catch such issues at runtime if it was.

Answer (score 3):

GetProcessesByName() returns an array.  It has a `Length` property to indicate the number of elements.

You might have accidentally used the Linq Enumerable.Count() extension method.  An edit that removed the `Imports` statement for System.Linq would be an explanation.  It is certainly best to use Length instead.

Comment: I updated my post to show my new code, the only problem with the new code is that the whole program doesn't close, onlt the window where the code is.